# Openshift online error - "Zero nodes available"

Tags: openshift, openshift-3, openshift-online

I am not able to bring up pods (Location: Canada - central)

I am getting following error; it seems that the nodes are not available. But cannot figure out the cause.

> 0/133 nodes are available: 1 node(s) were not ready, 126 node(s) had
>   taints that the pod didn't tolerate, 6 node(s) didn't match node
>   selector. 91 times in the last 27 minutes

Comment: Status page https://status.starter.openshift.com/ says upgrades in progress on clusters. You might be getting caught up in that.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep an eye on it.

Comment: Status page now says "All Systems Operational", but still facing the same error.

Comment: You can reach out to them using https://help.openshift.com/forms/community-contact.html